# Dart Generator Functions (yield / yield*)

Tags: dart, recursion

I am trying to understand how the generator functions work in dart/flutter.

There is a video from the flutter team [Generator Functions - Flutter in Focus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TF-TBsgIErY&list=PLjxrf2q8roU2HdJQDjJzOeO6J3FoFLWr2&index=20) where they discuss the following example.

```
Iterable<int> getRange(int start, int finish) sync* {
  if (start <= finish) {
    yield start;
    print('start: $start');

    
    for (final val in getRange(start+1, finish)) {
      yield val;
      print('val: $val');
    }
  }
}
```

only without the print lines.

I went and called that function in a main like this

```
void main() async {
    getRange(0, 3).forEach(print);
}
```

and got the following results:

```
0
start: 0
1
val: 1
start: 1
2
val: 2
val: 2
start: 2
3
val: 3
val: 3
val: 3
start: 3
```

The part from where I do not understand the output result is from

```
1
val: 1
start: 1
```

Why is the `start: 1`after the `val: 1`. I somehow do not get how the recursion in combination with the yield works. Also what happens when the `yield val;` gets read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good example of badly written code, doing strange things, is hard to understand because the code is badly written in the first place. To make debugging easier, I added the `start` variable to the `print` statements. Also removed `async` from your `main()` since nothing here is running asynchronously:

```
Iterable<int> getRange(int start, int finish) sync* {
  if (start <= finish) {
    yield start;
    print('(start = $start) start: $start');

    for (final val in getRange(start + 1, finish)) {
      yield val;
      print('(start = $start) val: $val');
    }
  }
}

void main() {
  getRange(0, 3).forEach(print);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
0
(start = 0) start: 0
1
(start = 0) val: 1
(start = 1) start: 1
2
(start = 0) val: 2
(start = 1) val: 2
(start = 2) start: 2
3
(start = 0) val: 3
(start = 1) val: 3
(start = 2) val: 3
(start = 3) start: 3
```

So the part you are asking about is now:

```
1
(start = 0) val: 1
(start = 1) start: 1
```

An important detail in your program is that you are doing `yield` BEFORE `print()`. So when you are doing `yield 1`, the value will move to your `print` statement in `main()` as the first thing. You can then see that your for-loop will do the `val` print before asking for the next value which would make the `start = 1` loop continue.

`yield` in `sync*` methods means the method deliver the value and stops executing the method until a new value is asked for.

Comment: I think I now got what my question was. So the 1st `yield start` is yielding the value into the main once at the beginning. Within the recursion it then yields the value in the function of the for-in loop. The `yield val` yields then the remaining values in the main.. The print just waites its turn after the `yield` has done it's job :)

Comment: @Georgios Yeah. You need to remember you have multiple methods which are in standby position until a new value is requested. Also, this code should never be seen in production since it is very inefficient but I fully understand if the code is made to try understand how things work. :P